# VHDL: convert "real" and "time" variables into strings for display on console

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I have some vhdl constants that are of type "real" and type "time", how can i convert them to a string and display them using "report" function?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mytop is
end entity;

architecture rtl of mytop is
    constant pi : real := 3.141;
    constant pi_time : time := pi * 1 ns;
begin

    process
    begin
        report "this is a real variable: " & pi; 
        report "this is a time variable: " & pi_time; 
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Result:

ERROR... pi and pi_time are not functions...

Comment: Dear pico, be pepared for a lot of frustration if you want to do the equivalent of `$display("%m, Error at address 0x%08X Have value 0x%04X expected 0x%04X",adrs,rvalue,expect);` Been there, not done that : given up!

Comment: The error messages should report there's no concatenation function declared with operands of string and real, a little more illuminating. Besides the predefined attribute providing a real value's string value as shown by Jonathan Drolet there's the conversion function to_string in -2008, useful in TEXTIO, which has a parameter FORMAT or DIGITS with a default value (The LRM - IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.6 Predefined operations on scalar types). You could also write your own conversion function(s).

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, a type's image attribute is a function that convert that type to a string representation:

```
report real'image(pi);
report time'image(pi_time);
```

Comment: Provides a string representation of the parameter value of the type specified in the prefix of the attribute. Types real and string aren't closely related for purposes of type conversion.